# Dynamicly insert Views into custom cell with Dynamic Height

Tags: ios, swift2, custom-cell, uitableview

Hello Guys i spend few days figuring out how to solve my problem and i am not much skilled in swift i decided ask some profesionals

My Problem:

DATA: array list of events(apointment, task, etc...)
number of events its not always same thats why i have to insert as many views as events in array and height of each cell is always different

custom cell created with xib file

[image]

I am inserting views inside cell ( creating column of apointments and tasks) but i have a problem when scrolling everything start to look really bad. Can someone help me and told my why it look like broken lego when scrolling ?

I want to make something like this[image]

I tried add label to left side of my column of views and it did not work. cell height was small and content did not appear because was hidden under next row. Cell height was only height of that one lable. It ignores constrains of last view and only notice constrain of that label

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var data = [PLCalendarDay]()

var tableView : UITableView!

let days = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for (var i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        var boleen = true
        if i > 2 {boleen = false}
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let day = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: i, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
        print("robim pole")
        self.data.append(PLCalendarDay(day: day!, withEnd: boleen))
    }
    tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "PLCalendarCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PLCalendarCellid")
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.separatorStyle = .None
    self.view.addSubview(tableView!)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    //        self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(indexesInRange: NSMakeRange(0, self.tableView.numberOfSections)), withRowAnimation: .None)
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("davam cell number")
    return data.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("davam cell")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PLCalendarCellid", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PLCalendarCell
    cell.setupCell(data[indexPath.row].events)
    //cell.selectionStyle = .None
   //      cell.day.text = data[indexPath.row].date.dateStringWithFormat("dd")
  //        let day = data[indexPath.row].date.dateStringWithFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
   //        cell.dayWord.text = days[getDayOfWeek(day)!-1]
    print("som awake1 1 1 ")
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // cell selected code here
}

func getDayOfWeek(today:String)->Int? {

    let formatter  = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    if let todayDate = formatter.dateFromString(today) {
        let myCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        let myComponents = myCalendar.components(.Weekday, fromDate: todayDate)
        let weekDay = myComponents.weekday
        return weekDay
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200
}
```

}

**cell file**

```
class PLCalendarCell: UITableViewCell {



@IBOutlet weak var day: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dayWord: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    print("som awake")
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

func setupCell (events: [PLCalendarEvent]){
    let cellWidht = self.contentView.frame.width
    var positionY:CGFloat = 10.0
    var lastView: UIView? = nil

    for event in events {

        if event.end != nil {

            let view = PLCalendarCellView(frame: CGRectMake(70, positionY, cellWidht, 50.0), time: true)
            view.title.text = event.desc
            view.time.text = "\(event.start.dateStringWithFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")) - \(event.end!.dateStringWithFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"))"
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            view.layer.cornerRadius = 4
            self.addSubview(view)
            if lastView == nil {
                let constrain =  NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
                self.addConstraint(constrain)
            } else {
                let constrain =  NSLayoutConstraint(item: lastView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
                self.addConstraint(constrain)
            }
            lastView = view
            positionY += 60.0

        }
        else {

            let view = PLCalendarCellView(frame: CGRectMake(70, positionY, cellWidht, 30.0), time: false)
            view.title.text = event.desc
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            view.layer.cornerRadius = 4
            self.addSubview(view)
            if lastView == nil {
                let constrain =  NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
                self.addConstraint(constrain)
            } else {
                let constrain =  NSLayoutConstraint(item: lastView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
                self.addConstraint(constrain)
            }
            lastView = view
            positionY += 40.0

        }
    }

   //        eventHolderView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cellWidht, positionY)

    //        let constrain =  NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: lastView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
  //        self.addConstraint(constrain)
    let constrain =  NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: lastView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
    self.addConstraint(constrain)

}
```

}

**Callendar day**

```
class PLCalendarDay: NSObject {
let date: NSDate!
var events = [PLCalendarEvent]()

init(day: NSDate, withEnd: Bool) {

    self.date = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(day)

    if withEnd {

        for(var i=0; i<5;i++){
            events.append(PLCalendarEvent(description: "Only one day", startDate: NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(date)))
        }

    } else {

        for(var i=0; i<5;i++){
            events.append(PLCalendarEvent(description: "Only one day", startDate: NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(date), endDate: date))
        }

    }

}
```

}

**Callendar event**

```
class PLCalendarEvent : NSObject{

let desc: String
let start: NSDate
var end: NSDate? = nil

init(description: String, startDate: NSDate) {
    self.desc = description
    self.start = startDate
}

init(description: String, startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate) {
    self.desc = description
    self.start = startDate
    self.end = endDate
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

i really cant achieve any good result i will be really thankful for help

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem. All i needed was proper constraints but not only vertical but even horizontal.